# Why does Windows 10 assign a different track number to my MP3 metadata?

Tags: audio, mp3, metadata

So I've been recording a daily podcast since the start of 2017, and I've noticed the following thing happening:

- I assign a track number when exporting to MP3 in Audacity: 
  [image: Audacity track export]
- The track number is correct when I play the track back in Foobar:

[image: Foobar playback display]

- But the track number is always exactly six numbers lower in the Windows metadata.

[image: Windows metadata]

This isn't the worst thing that's ever happened to me -- I just fix it in Windows -- but why does this happen, and is there a simple way to make it stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried downloading the pictured file, but your website [is blocking visits from my country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdUwc.png). (Or trying to, in any case.) So I used a VPN and downloaded it anyway.

According to MP3Diags, your tags are fine. However, notice that `034` in [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) = `28` decimal.

So the problem appears to be that Windows 10 interprets numbers with a leading `0` as octal, possibly due to the developers forgetting to explicitly specify base 10. (For example, the C function `strtoul()` autodetects decimal/hex/octal unless told otherwise.)

Try specifying the track number without any leading zeros – it gets interpreted as a number by all players anyway, so the zeros aren't necessary for proper sorting.